# Stackig vertically .csv files with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have been trying to merge .csv files with Pandas, and trying to create a couple of functions to automate it but I keep having an issue.
My problem is that I want to stack one .csv after the other(same number of columns and different number of rows) but instead of getting a bigger csv with the same numer of columns , I get a bigger csv with more columns and rows(correct number of rows, incorrect number of columns(more columns than the ones that are supposed to be)).
The code Im using is this one:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def stackcsv(content_folder):
    global combined_csv
    combined_csv= []
    entries = os.listdir(content_folder)
    for i in entries:
        csv_path = os.path.join(content_folder, i)
        solo_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path,index_col=None)
        combined_csv.append(solo_csv)
   csv_final = pd.concat(combined_csv,axis = 0,ignore_index=True)
   return csv_final.to_csv("final_data.csv",index = None, header = None)
```

I have 3.csv files that have a size of 20000x17, and I want to merge it into one of 60000x17. I suppose my error must be in the arguments of index, header, index_col, etc.... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the files have header lines?

Comment: No, no headers. Ill add them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files have no header you **must** say it to `read_csv`. If you don't, the first line of each file is read as a header line. As a result the DataFrames have different column names and `concat` will add new columns. So you should read with:

```
solo_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path,index_col=None, header=None)
```

Alternatively, there is no reason to decode them, and you could just concatenate the sequential files:

```
def stackcsv(content_folder):
    with open("final_data.csv", "w") as fdout
        entries = os.listdir(content_folder)
        for i in entries:
            csv_path = os.path.join(content_folder, i)
            with open(csv_path) as fdin:
                while True:
                    chunk = fdin.read()
                    if len(chunk) == 0: break
                    fdout.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1):

So after modifying the code, it worked. First of all, as Serge Ballesta said, it is necesary to say to the `read_csv` that there is no header. Finally, using the `sort = False`, the function works perfectly. This is the final code that I have used, and the final .csv is 719229 rows × 17 columns long. Thanks to everbody!

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def stackcsv(content_folder):
 global combined_csv
    combined_csv= []
    entries = os.listdir(content_folder)
    for i in entries:
        csv_path = os.path.join(content_folder, i)
        solo_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path,index_col=None,header = None)
        combined_csv.append(solo_csv)
   csv_final = pd.concat(combined_csv,axis = 0,sort = False)
   return csv_final.to_csv("final_data.csv", header = None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter sort to False in the pandas concat function:

```py
 csv_final = pd.concat(combined_csv, axis = 0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Comment: If there are no headers in the input csv file, the first line of each file will be lost...